# fillMaxSize() on Scaffold content having no impact

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a short content center-aligned on the screen inside a `Scaffold` content. Using `fillMaxSize()` on the scaffold contents seems like having no impact at all. How can I make this content full size?

[image]

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = { },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
    floatingActionButton = { },
    bottomBar = { }
) { paddingValues ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(paddingValues)
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Running.route
        ) {
            composable(Screen.Business.route) {
                BusinessScreen(onSetAppTitle = { appTitle = it })
            }
            ...
        }
```

```
@Composable
fun BusinessScreen(onSetAppTitle: (String) -> Unit) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        onSetAppTitle("Business Dashboard")
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Business Dashboard")
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I need vertical scroll for the other screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verticalScroll` wraps content, and can be stretched to very long. That's why `.fillMaxHeight` (which is a part of `fillMaxSize`) doesn't work inside `verticalScroll`: it's ambiguous.

You need to set `height` explicitly. This is the case when you can pass it from `onSizeChanged` modifier added on the top `Column`.

But I believe that your composition is generally not really good: applying `verticalScroll` to a view on top of the layout tree is not the best solution.

Try adding `verticalScroll` inside each route only to those views that are really bigger than the screen.

Comment: All the screens are supposed to be bigger than the screens when the app will be in use. So added the vertical scroll once, instead of doing it on every screen.

Comment: Setting `fillMaxWidth()` `height(640.dp)` exclusively on the screen done the work. Thanks!

Comment: @RawHasan this particular view doesn't seem bigger than the screen=) `height(640.dp)` will look different on different devices

Comment: This is a temporary view. Want to make it full size just to look good, and also to learn about the issue.